# Application tool to perform cross browser testing within localhost

Tags: php, testing, cross-browser

I am in the middle of building a website which means it is not uploaded to a server yet. Is there any way I can perform cross browser testing from the localhost and not an actual hosted URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either by running lots of browsers natively (some in a VM), or by using SSH tunnelling to a commercial service like browserling (http://browserling.com/).

Edit to elaborate a bit: An SSH tunnel (a *reverse* tunnel technically) between your localhost and a server allows you to forward certain ports on the remote host to ports on your localhost, over an encrypted SSH channel. This means the browsers running on browserling's servers can send packets down the tunnel, back to your localhost and your webserver there.

Comment: sounds interesting - I will see if I can give this a go

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP on your local machine, this way you can run PHP scripts in command-line or browsers.

http://php.net/manual/en/install.php

Answer (score 0):

Configure your webserver to listen on your network IP and access your website through IP address on your local network.

If it is apache webserver It would be configured using directive:

```
Listen IP:port
```

Example 1 (your adapter IP address):

```
Listen 192.168.1.10:80
```

Example 2 (global listening on all interfaces) - better for testing

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Then just simply access your computer from other browsers on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  If you're able to configure your local network you could expose port 80 or 443 to the cloud by making changes to your routers firewall.  This would make your application as available for testing locally as any on a remote host.

Let me know if your question is about which tools you could use, either as external services or locally installable.